# Deploy app in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

**while deplying app in google app engine i always got following errors...**

```
 2014-08-10 03:30:58 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=rjt.rjtshrm94@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', u'C:\\Users\\Rjt\\Desktop\\New folder (3)']"
03:31 AM Application: my-app-chat; version: 1
03:31 AM Host: appengine.google.com
03:31 AM 
Starting update of app: my-app-chat, version: 1
03:31 AM Getting current resource limits.
Password for rjt.rjtshrm94@gmail.com: Invalid username or password.
2014-08-10 03:31:08,612 ERROR appcfg.py:2415 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. Aborting. 
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
Must authenticate first.
--- end server output ---
2014-08-10 03:31:08 (Process exited with code 1)
```

but my emailid and password are correct....

```
You can close this window now.
```

Comment: For me it's an authentication problem. Another post with the same error talk about a time setting problem, maybe you have the same trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686718/google-app-engine-says-must-authenticate-first-while-trying-to-deploy-any-app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was driving me mad. I wasn't typing the password wrong.

For me, changing a security setting, not in the app but in my Google account solved it. Go here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and "Enable" less secure devices and apps to access your data. For me, that fixed it.

Otherwise I've come accross time settings being the problem (mentioned above).

But more importantly, double-check that the name of your app, that you registered on GoogleDev, is the name that you put in the app.yaml. If it is, then hitting the dashboard in the Launcher should take you to the dashboard of your app.

See [my question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923756/google-appengine-deployment-authorization-problems/) for more information, if none of this works.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  Essentially by doing above, I was removing two-factor authentication to gmail account.  (How annoying..)