# google appengine deployment authorization problems

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, deployment

Im having problems deploying my GAE. I've got two running already so I should have all the right lirbaries and whatnot. But obviously Im missing something.

1. I registered my applet with googe appengine developers.
2. i enter the app_id in the app.yaml of the project as application name.
3. in cmd, i go to google_appengine and run the "appcfg.py update" on the root directory of my project. "C:/Development/GAE/projectname"
4. type in email and pw,

and then i get this error msg

```
12:47 AM Application: processing#######; version: 1
12:47 AM Host: appengine.google.com
12:47 AM 
Starting update of app: processing######, version: 1
12:47 AM Getting current resource limits.
Password for ###########@gmail.com: Invalid username or password.
2014-09-19 00:47:36,404 ERROR appcfg.py:2416 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error       401: Unauthorized. Aborting. 
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
Must authenticate first.
--- end server output ---
```

Any ideas what Im missing? Ive triple-checked all these steps cause thats all i can think of.

My App.yaml contains this

```
application: processing######
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /statics
  static_dir: statics

- url: /sketches
  static_dir: sketches

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2                                                                  
  version: latest
```

Ive upgraded my GAE to the latest version too, still no change. I also tried uploading it to a different application, same problem.
Ive added 2 static folder I use for to run Processing embedded in my website.

PS my app runs fine locally and there's nothing that throws errors or doesnt compile. I think the fault lies somewehre else.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Ok so as usual, more research eventually revealed the answer. And stackoverflow.
Guess I missed this first because it specified with php.[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387063/google-app-engine-deploy-failing-with-error-1-unauthorised)

Basically i wasnt doing anything wrong afterall, the permission problem was that it was being blocked by my google account. 
I had to go to my [Account Security permissions](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps), and enable access from less-secure devices.

This must be a new, recent setting Google changed, becuase Ive already deployed 2 apps before.

To mention here for other people with  the same problem:
First go through the steps I went through to make sure everything is set up correctly.

Then you should solving it the way I did.

Otherwise you can try setting it up so you can upload without password, this might avoid the problem if it lies somewehre else [--oauth without pw](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2)

Finally I read that for some people the problem was in timezones. When the time on their computer was different to GAE or server I think that lead to miscommunication, so double-check that your time is set correctly and that it agrees with the time you see in the Launcher Log.

Answer (score 2):

well for me the below 02 options worked

```
appcfg.py update . --oauth2 --noauth_local_webserver
```

The authentication flow was :

the command and options generated a url in stdout, which i copied and accessed from my browser, the browser generated a code, which I gave in my command line. I could see appcfg as one of the apps under connected apps and services of my google account.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an error with your user or password.

Are you sure you can access the project in the [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/), the email configured under permissions is the one which you are using to connect and the app id in yaml file is the same ID on the developers console? If so, the only thing I can imagine is a fail in your password.

Maybe a key pressed? Try typing it in a text processor.

A last idea, deploy the app via the launcher of the sdk. Add the existing app in the file menu (search the app.yaml file) and click deploy to see if there you can authenticate.

Comment: Hey, yeah ive loaded it in the AppEngine Launcher and tried there too. the appID is correct because hitting dashboard takes me to the  correct dashboard. I am the owner of the app, and yes, ive doublechecked im typing the correct password and logged in and out of gmail to make sure im not dreaming. ive tried gmail and googlemail. I created a new app to see if the fault lay there, but no difference.